# How to force use of internal GPU

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

Okay so it's likely the case that I have a misunderstanding of how this works, but I have blacklisted the `nvidia` and `nouveau` modules, `lspci` confirms that there is no active driver (although kernel modules `nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia`are still listed) and yet I still get display output on the card.

For context, I am trying to disable output on my external GPU and use only the internal GPU for general use, then use the external GPU for a secondary X server or a VM when I need to use it.

My BIOS is set to use internal graphics, and GRUB outputs on the IGPU before handing over to the external GPU.

If I've missed any important details out, please tell me. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I'm not exactly sure what I've done, but the same thing happens while using the `pci-stub` driver, which previously caused output to be from the Intel GPU only. I cannot start an x server (cannot run in framebuffer mode) or GDM currently. 
Something strange I noticed is that the Intel card is still outputting, it's just a black screen. During boot they flash off/on as the drivers kick in and update the resolution but all output is still on the Nvidia card.

Comment: not an answer to the overarching question, but the GPU is probably now operating in some VGA compatible mode.

Comment: @Yorik I'd imagine you're probably correct. In which case, how do I stop it from doing that and force it to use the IGPU?

Comment: Have you tried also blacklisting nvidia_drm ?

Comment: @plugwash just tried it now, no change

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly X Server ignoring BIOS setting so just remove X GPU modules:

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu*
```

in case of amd.